# Visual Studio out of memory with only 500mb and 23gb available

Tags: visual-studio, memory

Visual studio 2019 Throws out of memory exception.
When i look at the task manager it uses 500MB.
I have over 30GB available.

I know that VS is a 32 bit application and has a lower limit on memory it can use, but it still does not seem right.

Why would that be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Not all out of memory exceptions are caused from the lack of available memory. Other resources can be the cause of the problem. Specifically things like GDI handles.

If you hit the issue make sure you report a problem in VS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019. If there's a crash you can also upload open a ticket and upload that.